# Python MSAL REST Graph: is it possible to get all files in folder, not just 200, in one request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I need to delete all files from a OneDrive folder. When I issue a request like the one shown under `# Listing children(all files and folders) within General` **[here](https://python.plainenglish.io/all-you-need-to-know-file-handing-in-sharepoint-using-python-df43fde60813)**, I only get 200 items, which seems to be the expected default behavior per **[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)**. So in order to delete all files, I repeat the request multiple times, each time deleting 200 files. Is it possible to get ALL children in one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
link = parent+":/children"
while True:
    rGetCh = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

    for ch in rGetCh.json()["value"]:
        # Looping through the current list of children
        chName = urllib.parse.quote(ch["name"].encode('utf8'))
        chPath = parent + "/" + chName
        
    if "@odata.nextLink" in rGetCh.json():  # if this is in the response, there are more children
       link =  rGetCh.json()["@odata.nextLink"]
    else:
       break
```